# Google cloud storage bucket is getting unmounted

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, gcsfuse

I am running some application on google compute engine where it the application reads the data from google cloud storage and writes data to persistent disk. And the bucket is mounted using gcsfuse.

But in the middle the bucket is getting unmounted and my application is going to sleep mode and getting stalled.

When I try to see the content in Mounted directory I am getting following error
 cannot access /home/santhosh/MountPoint/ Transport endpoint is not connected

Is there any time limit on the bucket live? How can we see the bucket is mounted all the time?

Can someone please help me how can I resolve this? I want the program to run without any breaks in the middle.

Comment: What version of the fuser has been installed? try this command to unmount the bucket: `fusermount -u /home/santhosh/MountPoint/` and try running it as a daemon: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md

Comment: Hi Kamra, Thank you for you reply. $fuser -V command show below out put.  fuser (PSmisc) 22.20
Copyright (C) 1993-2010 Werner Almesberger and Craig Small
PSmisc comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under
the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the files named COPYING. I will try running it as a deamon and see if it is still breaking in the middle

Comment: This is working well. But very slow in read and write.

Comment: Also, I am trying to access files in he bucket from apache server by providing symbolic link. But I am getting access denied error message. Can you help me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I experience same problems, random I/O errors, unmounting. Do not use `gcsfuse` in production, from the doc: "Please treat gcsfuse as beta-quality software." We use it for the maintenance only.